# How to use advanced excel counting formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel Question:

I have quarterly dates in Row 1, and I have "new capital committed" values in Row 4, and I am writing formulas in the columns (A-Z).

Is there any way to write a formula that gives me the difference (in months) between the current quarter I am in and the quarter in which the capital was committed?

For example: If cell D1 has 6/30/2013 in it, and cell A4 has 9/30/2012 in it, is there a formula that I can use to get the number of months difference between those two dates, USING a dynamic formula so I can copy and past the formula to other parts of the excel file?

Thank you!

R1

Comment: Try this: `=(year(d1) - year(a4)) * 12 + (month(d1) - month(a4))`

Comment: I have to tell you: you should at least try to solve your problem yourself and post your efforts, so we can help you. Besides that, this is not a programming related question (which is the scope of this site)

Comment: This is a software use question, and is more appropriate for [su].

Answer (score 0):

`DATEDIF` function gives you the number of full months between two dates, e.g.

`=DATEDIF(A4,D1,"m")`

It's not very well documented in Excel -see [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx)